# Showing that a Unit Speed Curve is a Circle.

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

In my recent differential geometry tutorial, we were given the question:

---

Given the unit speed curve,

$$\boldsymbol{r}(s)=\left(\frac{4}{5}\cos(s),1-\sin(s),-\frac{3}{5}\cos(s)\right)$$

show that this represents a circle with centre $(0,1,0)$ with radius 1.

---

My first intuitive thought is to simply find the distance between $(0,1,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{r}(s)$ and show that it is 1 for all $s$ - this is the definition of a circle, correct? However, my tutor advised that we had to look into the torsion of the curve and use the fact that it is 0.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: For a non-torsion approach, you could use the curve to deduce what the equation of the plane would have to be and show that your curve indeed lies in it.

Comment: The curve lies in the plane: $ z = -\frac{3}{4} x $ .

Comment: Even if you show the points of your curve lie on a circle, you still have to prove they describe the whole circle. It looks obvious, but you may also have a curve describing only half a circle, for example. You can find an orthogonal linear transformation in space that transform your curve in the parametric equation of a circle in an easy plane like xOy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that in three dimension, a curve of constant distant to a fixed point is a curve on the sphere. So not only you shall show what you mentioned, but that torsion vanishes to ensure the curve is restricted to a plane, hence a circle in 2 dimensional subspace.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That make sense. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

By looking at x,y and z coordinates, notice that the curve is intersection of an elliptic cylinder and plane through y-axis at a certain angle to get equal axes for the ellipse.. as circle.Directly use Frenet-Serret to find that torsion vanishes, curvature is constant.

Answer (score 0):

With the rotation matrix around axis $Oy$,

$$R_\theta=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta & 0 & -\sin \theta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

And

$$r=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac45\cos s\\
1-\sin s\\
-\frac35\cos s
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then

$$R_\theta \cdot r=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{(3\sin \theta + 4\cos \theta)\cos s}5\\
1-\sin s \\
\frac{(4\sin \theta - 3\cos\theta)\cos s}5 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Thus, with $\theta=\mathrm{Arctan} \frac34$, the third component vanishes, and (you've got a $3-4-5$ triangle):

$$\cos \theta=\frac45, \ \sin\theta=\frac35$$

So

$$R_\theta \cdot r=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{(3\sin \theta + 4\cos \theta)\cos s}5\\
1-\sin s \\
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos s\\
1-\sin s \\
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

So the rotated curve has a simpler equation.